# How to allow a temporary Drawer close without the content disappearing on URL change in React Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-v4

How can I make a temporary Drawer close gracefully (with transition) before the content disappearing on URL change in a SPA? I'm using React Router 4 and this is roughly how I construct my code:

```
<Drawer open={this.state.shouldDrawerOpen}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='x'/>
  </Switch>
</Drawer>
```

The app would decide whether to close the Drawer on `getDerivedStateFromProps`, but while closing, the content is already blank and cause the slide out transition looks broken.  Is it possible to restructure the code somehow to allow the content to be unmounted after the drawer is fully closed (after the slide-out transition)?

One drawer per path might work, but it will be tricky to manage.

Comment: Cant we get some more code for the bigger picture? I am trying to understand what you are meaning, but not sure why you are rendering routes inside of a sliding drawer.

Comment: @remoo think a messaging app, url `/` will have no drawer, but if url changes to say `/chats/some_chat_id` will open up the drawer.  When the user clicks back, the drawer will be closed, but the `switch` already renders blank so the slide out is broken.  Thanks!